# Date is a text and cannot be coerced to a number

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to search for data from the Masterlist to the Data Entry Form but got an error saying **Date is a text and cannot be coerced to a number**, Column G consists of a formula where it will calculate number of days between two date (column E & F).

But when i tried to pull data from the Masterlist using Search button an error pop up mentioning **Date is a text and cannot be coerced to a number** (refer to Image 1)

Image 1: Error
[image]

I already tried to format the column but the problem still persists as it converts the date to text not number when I tried to search the data. Below is the code used:

```
var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "Billing Masterlist"
var SEARCH_COL_year = 0;
var SEARCH_COL_hospital = 1;

function searchStr() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Data Entry Form");

  var hospital = formSS.getRange("B7").getValue();
  var year = formSS.getRange("D7").getValue();

  var values = ss.getSheetByName("Billing Masterlist").getDataRange().getValues();
  var cont = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)

  {
    var row = values[i];

    if ((row[SEARCH_COL_year] == year && row[SEARCH_COL_hospital] == hospital ))

    {

      var s = (11 + cont).toString();
      formSS.getRange("B" + s).setValue(row[2]);
      formSS.getRange("E" + s).setValue(row[4]);
      formSS.getRange("F" + s).setValue(row[5]);
      cont = cont + 1;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The output doesn’t show calculated value when i pull data from the masterlist . (Refer image).

Comment: Please explain `calculated value` and where does you script access the master list? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: If dd/mm/yyyy is a valid format in your region, make sure your region is set correctly in spreadsheet settings and your Google account.  This will only work with dates input in the future. For dates already input, you should change the format to yyyy-mm-dd and input it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the format for both of the spreadsheets so that they tally to each other, Thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating Days between two dates

Data:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start | End | Days |
| 2 | 1/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 3 | 2/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 4 | 3/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 5 | 4/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 6 | 5/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 7 | 6/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 8 | 7/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 9 | 8/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 10 | 9/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 11 | 10/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 12 | 11/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 13 | 12/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 14 | 13/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 15 | 14/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 16 | 15/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 17 | 16/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 18 | 17/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 19 | 18/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |
| 20 | 19/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 |  |

gs:

```
function days(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hs,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
  const o = vs.map(([a,b]) => {
    let t0 = a.split('/')
    let s = new Date(Number(t0[2]),Number(t0[1])-1,Number(t0[0]));
    let t1 = b.split('/');
    let e = new Date(Number(t1[2]),Number(t1[1])-1,Number(t1[0]));
    return [timeDiff(s,e)];
  });
  sh.getRange(2,3,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o)
}
```

helper function:

```
function timeDiff(Start, End) {
  if (Start && End) {
    var second = 1000;
    var minute = 60 * second;
    var hour = minute * 60;
    var day = hour * 24;
    var t1 = new Date(Start).valueOf();
    var t2 = new Date(End).valueOf();
    var d = t2 - t1;
    var days = Math.floor(d / day);
    var hours = Math.floor(d % day / hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor(d % day % hour / minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor(d % day % hour % minute / second);
    //return 'dd:hh:mm:ss\n' + days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;  
    return d / day;
    //return hours + minutes/60;
  }
  else {
    return 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```

Output:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start | End | Days |
| 2 | 1/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 30 |
| 3 | 2/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 29 |
| 4 | 3/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 28 |
| 5 | 4/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 27 |
| 6 | 5/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 26 |
| 7 | 6/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 25 |
| 8 | 7/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 24 |
| 9 | 8/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 23 |
| 10 | 9/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 22 |
| 11 | 10/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 21 |
| 12 | 11/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 20 |
| 13 | 12/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 19 |
| 14 | 13/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 18 |
| 15 | 14/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 17 |
| 16 | 15/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 16 |
| 17 | 16/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 15 |
| 18 | 17/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 14 |
| 19 | 18/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 13 |
| 20 | 19/1/2024 | 31/1/2024 | 12 |

- [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)
- [Javascript Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)